# pthread and mutex_lock throwing segmentation core dumped

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to play with **threads** using a **mutex** for syncronization, but it seems that my code throws a "**segmentation fault core dumped**" error every time after compiling it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int *s = 0;
void *fonction(void * arg0) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( & mutex);
    *s += *((int *)arg0) * 1000000;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
int main() {
    pthread_t thread[5];
    int ordre[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        ordre[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, fonction, & ordre[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

    printf("%d\n", * s);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You don't initialize your `mutex`. You may initialize the global variable using
`pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: thanks, but still throwing the same error .i will try looking in my code once again

Comment: `s` is uninitialized, doesn't point to valid memory.

Comment: ack! Get rid of those `5` and use a constant or variable!

Comment: sure thanks lmao using constants make your code always more readable

Comment: My main concern is actually how error prone having `5` in four difference places. Imagine how easy it would be to miss one if you wanted to change to `6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are dereferencing a NULL pointer here:

   ```
   *s += *((int *)arg0) * 1000000;
   ```

   Since you define `int *s = 0;` globally. You probably wanted to define it as `int s = 0;` and then use `s` everywhere instead of `*s`.
2. [As noted by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339175/pthread-and-mutex-lock-throwing-segmentation-core-dumped/70339382#comment124339117_70339175) [Rainer Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5116723/rainer-keller) in the comments, you are not initializing your `mutex`. You should either initialize it statically to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, or at runtime in `main` with `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex)`.